# Русские символы не отображаются при чтении CSV

Tags: java, csv

Столкнулся с проблемой не читаемости русских символов в файле **CSV**.

В результате получаю:

```
����������� ��������
```

Вот мой код:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), ',' , '"' , 1);
String[] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            if (nextLine != null) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nextLine));
            }
        }
```

Использую пакет **opencsv**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFile), "UTF-8"), ',' , '"' , 1);
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает.

Comment: Странно, у меня работает. Кодировка консоли у вас какая?

Comment: У меня UTF-8 стоит..

Comment: Тогда тем более странно. Может у вас файл не в UTF-8 кодировке?

Comment: Экспериментировал с настройками и скачал позднюю версию commons-lang3, ничего не помогло...

Comment: Решил. Проблема была в кодировке файла. Методом подбора нашел кодировку (Cp1251), всё заработало. Спасибо за код. Сам бы не справился))

Comment: @ПавелДаушко [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).